# Unpacking Python's Type Annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, inspect, type-hinting

I'm trying to generate some JavaScript based on the type annotations I have provided in on some Python functions by using the `signature()` function in the `inspect` module.

This part works as I expect when the type is a simple builtin class:

```
import inspect

def my_function() -> dict:
    pass

signature = inspect.signature(my_function)
signature.return_annotation is dict  # True
```

Though I'm not sure how to unwrap and inspect more complex annotations e.g:

```
from typing import List
import inspect

def my_function() -> List[int]:
    pass

signature = inspect.signature(my_function)
signature.return_annotation is List[int]  # False
```

Again similar problem with forward referencing a custom class:

```
def my_function() -> List['User']:
    pass
...
signature.return_annotation  # typing.List[_ForwardRef('User')]
```

What I'm looking to get out is something like this - so I can branch appropriately while generating the JavaScript:

```
type = signature.return_annotation... # list
member_type = signature.return_annotation... # int / 'User'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3.8 provides `typing.get_origin()` and `typing.get_args()` for this!

```
assert get_origin(Dict[str, int]) is dict
assert get_args(Dict[int, str]) == (int, str)

assert get_origin(Union[int, str]) is Union
assert get_args(Union[int, str]) == (int, str)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin

Answer (score 9):

`List` is not a map of types to `GenericMeta`, despite the syntax. Each access to it generates a new instance:

```
>>> [ id(List[str]) for i in range(3) ]
[33105112, 33106872, 33046936]
```

This means that even `List[int] is not List[int]`. To compare two instances, you have multiple options:

- Use `==`, i.e., `signature.return_annotation == List[int]`.
- Store an instance of your type in a global variable and check against that, i.e.,

  ```
  a = List[int]
  def foo() -> a:
      pass
  inspect.signature(foo).return_annotation is a
  ```
- Use `issubclass`. The typing module defines that. Note that this might do more than you'd like, make sure to read the `_TypeAlias` documentation if you use this.
- Check against `List` only and read the contents yourself. Though the property is internal, it is unlikely that the implementation will change soon: `List[int].__args__[0]` contains the type argument starting from Python 3.5.2, and in earlier versions, its `List[int].__parameters__[0]`.

If you'd like to write generic code for your exporter, then the last option is probably best. If you only need to cover a specific use case, I'd personally go with using `==`.

Comment: I had figured out that it was creating new instances but I somehow didn't make the leap to recognise that `==` would be appropriate (feel a bit silly for that one) - thanks. Do you know about how I should go about deconstructing the constituent types?

Answer (score 4):

#### Take note, this applies to Python 3.5.1

***For Python 3.5.2 take a look at phillip's answer.***

You shouldn't be checking with the identity operator as Phillip stated, use equality to get this right.

To check if a hint is a subclass of a `list` you could use `issubclass` checks (even though you should take note that this can be quirky in certain cases and is currently worked on):

```
issubclass(List[int], list)  # True
```

To get the members of a type hint you generally have two watch out for the cases involved.

If it has a simple type, as in `List[int]` the value of the argument is located in the `__parameters__` value:

```
signature.return_annotation.__parameters__[0] # int
```

Now, in more complex scenarios i.e a class supplied as an argument with `List[User]` you must again extract the `__parameter__[0]` and then get the `__forward_arg__`. This is because Python wraps the argument in a special `ForwardRef` class:

```
d = signature.return_annotation.__parameter__[0]
d.__forward_arg__ # 'User'
```

*Take note*, you don't need to actually use `inspect` here, `typing` has a helper function named `get_type_hints` that returns the type hints as a dictionary (it uses the function objects `__annotations__` attribute).

Comment: Which Python version do you use? At least with Python 3.5.2, there is no `__parameters__` property; see my answer, its `__args__` there. `__forward_arg__` isn't set either.

Comment: @Phillip Godamnit it changes so quickly, nice catch.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Jim. I've given the answer to @Phillip but I've also used some of your answer. I don't believe there is a way on stack-overflow to split the reputation (if there is let me know and I'll slice you off some of the cake). Thanks to both of you. How did you go about finding the answer to this question? I was unable to find the documentation I needed online. Did you use the source code's documentation?

Comment: @freebie Give the bounty to Phillip, his answer addresses the most recent changes made to the `typing` module, just don't award it immediately, wait for the bounty period to end (new answers may come, more people will see this question and might find it interesting). As for how, you could look at it's source or, how I do it, fire up `IPython` and introspect the object.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for the tips :)