# Unpack Optional type annotation in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

Given this example:

```
import typing

def foo(bar: int = None):
    pass

typing.get_type_hints(foo)
```

The type hint for `bar` is `typing.Union[int, None]`. How do I get `int` from that? Neither the `__args__` nor `__parameters__` property seems to work in Python 3.5.2.

---

More concretely, I'm trying to write a generic decorator that inspects the signature of a function and does specific things to the arguments. For that it needs to get the class from an annotation such as `Optional[T]` to then work with `T`:

```
annot = typing.Optional[T]
cls = # MAGIC?!
assert cls is T
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `annot.__args__[0]` (in `3.6.1`, at least). What Python version are you using? `typing` is still [provisional](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0411/) and, as such, changes might still be made.

Comment: Needs to work on 3.5 for now.

Comment: You're using `3.5.2` I'm guessing? In `3.5.1` I think `__args__` is named `__parameters__`  so take note of that (the internal API of the `typing` module is pretty volatile.)

Comment: Ah right, I had answered a similar Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703556/unpacking-pythons-type-annotations.

Comment: Right, I'm just poking around it with different versions and there's some discrepancy there indeed…

Comment: None of that seems to actually work in 3.5.2, I'm retracting my earlier comment.

Comment: Well `__args__` is used in a `3.7.0` I have here so it seems like that *might* be here to stay.

Comment: `AttributeError: type object 'Union' has no attribute '__args__'` nor `__parameters__`

Comment: 3.5.2? Why not 3.5.4?

Comment: @MSeifert Reality. ;-) The production environment is on that version for now. It's slated for an upgrade to 3.6 later this year, but for now it's what it is.

Comment: Yup, `Union` seems to be different in `3.5.2`, use `__union_params__` there :-D. Note that this has changed to `__args__` in later versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `3.5.2`, to get the parameters for a `Union`, you'll have to use `__union_params__`.

```
>>> from typing import Union
>>> d = Union[int, str]
>>> print(*d.__union_params__)
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
```

This, unfortunately, seems to *only* apply until `3.5.2`, it was changed in `3.5.3` to use `__args__`:

```
>>> from typing import Union
>>> t = Union[int, str]
>>> t.__union_params__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_Union' object has no attribute '__union_params__'
>>> print(*t.__args__)
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
```

and has stayed `__args__` in later versions (`3.6` and `3.7`).

This is due to the provisional status of the typing module. Many aspects of the internal API are changing between micro version so you'll probably have to deal with a lot of obscure changes.

Answer (score 3):

In these cases I prefer to simply consult the implementation. In 3.5.2 this is the [`__repr__` of `Union`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Lib/typing.py#L536-L541):

```
def __repr__(self):
    r = super().__repr__()
    if self.__union_params__:
        r += '[%s]' % (', '.join(_type_repr(t)
                                 for t in self.__union_params__))
    return r
```

This suggests that the class is stored in the `__union_params__` attribute:

```
typing.get_type_hints(foo)['bar'].__union_params__[0] is T
```

This was however changed to `__args__` in [the commit `5fc25a873cfdec27e46f71e62c9b65df5667c1b4`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5fc25a873cfdec27e46f71e62c9b65df5667c1b4) for 3.5.3.