# Python: Get type of `typing.List`

Tags: python

I have annotated the arguments of a function as

```
import typing

def f(x: typing.List[MyType]):
    ...
```

By inspecting the parameter arguments, I get for the type of `x`, an instance of `typing.GenericMeta` which is, correctly, printed as `typing.List[MyType]`

How can I get the `List` and `MyType` from this object?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703556/unpacking-pythons-type-annotations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get `MyType`, you can find it under `.__args__`:

```
import typing

def f(x: typing.List[MyType]):
    ...

print(f.__annotations__["x"].__args__[0])  # prints <class '__main__.MyType'>
```

`List` (i.e. `typing.List`) is accessible from `.__base__`, and the actual list class comes from `.__orig_bases__`:

```
print(f.__annotations__["x"].__base__)  # prints typing.List[float]
print(f.__annotations__["x"].__orig_bases__[0])  # prints <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where is this documented?

Comment: I don't know, I just experimented with `dir`.

Comment: `__base__` and `__orig_bases__` don't appear to work in python 3.9

Comment: In 3.9, you can get `typing.List[MyType]` through `f.__annotations__["x"]` directly, and `list` through `f.__annotations__["x"].__origin__`

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.8+, use the [typing module introspection helpers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#introspection-helpers) [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) and [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args):

```py
import typing


class MyType:
    ...


def f(x: typing.List[MyType]):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    type_hints = typing.get_type_hints(f)
    type_args = typing.get_args(type_hints["x"])
    print(type_args[0])  # prints <class '__main__.MyType'>
```

Comment: It's also possible to use those introspection helpers for python3.7 by using the [typing-extension](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) backport